# Proof of Theorem 7.3 in book of Probabilistic Graphical Models by Daphne Koller

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, graphical-model

I'm studying graphical models myself and reading contents about bayesian networks. When I am reading in page 371, section 8.1.4 Linear-Gaussian models, in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, I cannot derive myself the equation of

$$\mathrm{Cov}[x_i, x_j] = \sum\left(w_{jk}  \mathrm{cov}[x_i,x_k]\right) + I_{ij}v_j  $$

where $x_k$ are the parents of $x_j$, especially I don't know how the second term $I_{ij}v_j$ comes.

I try to find the proof in other references, like in Probabilistic Graphical Models by Koller. There is a theorem 7.3 in the page 251 which states the same thing as the above equation, but it also does not supply a proof.

Comment: Oh, Comp_Warrior, you edit it! Thanks! The formula looks beautiful! How do you do it?

Comment: This second parameter looks like a regularization term to the covariance matrix but I am not sure !!

Comment: I guess there is nothing to do with regularization here:-(

Comment: Let vj be some value and I, the identity matrix, then, by adding Iijvj to the covariance matrix, you are conditioning the diagonal elements of the covaraince matrix. This is a standard approach to regularize the covariance matrix towards a more accurate estimation.

Comment: Maybe there is an implicit relationship between the second term with the regularization mechanism. But I actually want to know how the second term is derived:-(. If I assume the equation above is true, an equation 

E[(xi - E[xi])*sqrt(vj)εj] = Iij*vj

must be true. Here εi is an random variable which satisfy E[εiεj]=Iij and E[εi]=0.

In this case, if the equation

xi - E[xi] = sqrt(vi)*εi

holds, then the second equation would hold. But I cannot understand why this can hold.